# select from two ranges depend on select from combobox

Tags: vba, range

i want to add combobox3 ( choose from two items ) and when i select item from it , change row source shown in combobox2 , then i select item from combobox2 to get its data using below code

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
On Error Resume Next
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("cash").Range("BF:BH")
Price.Value = ""
    On Error Resume Next
Price.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox2.Value, myRange, 2, 0)
unitplace.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox2.Value, myRange, 3, 0)
Price.Value = Format(Price, "#,###,##.00")
End Sub
```

Comment: can't you adopt the same code for `ComboBox3_Change()` event but changing `Worksheets("cash").Range("BF:BH")` to `Worksheets("cash").Range("BM:BO")`?

Comment: combobox2 linked with range (row source) , i want to change this range depend on select item from combobox3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you're after this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
    Me.ComboBox2.LinkedCell = "BM:BO"
End Sub
```

Comment: @mostafa, any feedback?